# ActionScript 3.0 on animate. Trying to manipulate an instance that was added (addChild) in a frame from another frame.

Tags: actionscript, instance, frame

I´m very new to AS. I´m trying to delete an instance that i created in a frame from another frame in animate, but everytime i try i get the same error: 1120:Access of undefined property error. The thing is that this instance is still on stage but i can´t do anything with it if i change from a frame to another.

Code in the frame that the instance was generated:

```
ico.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, segui1);
function segui1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var batata = new pep();
    addChild(batata);
    batata.x = 448;
    batata.y = 277;

    resposta[2] = 1;
    gotoAndStop(49);
}

heli.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, segui2);
function segui2(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    resposta[2] = 0;
    gotoAndStop(49);

}
```

Code in the frame that i´m trying to delete the instance:

```
removeChild(batata);
```

Comment: working with frames, is not a good solution. You added batata in frame 1, but not to stage (where you can remove in frame 2). So if you would like to refer to it, you got this error. Instead try stage.addChild(batata). and remove it with stage.removeChild(batata). That should work.

Comment: I tryied that but it gave me the same error.

Comment: Do you know another thing that i can do?

Comment: Actually it worked, but i needed to declare the var outside the function too. Thanks man!!

Comment: ahh, hmm, sorry i forgot, has something to do with the scope